# Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge Ep. 1

Tags: visual, geography

I've just found something fun when I tried to give hint in [What is a BEN Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87941/what-is-a-ben-number). Let's find whether this puzzle could get well-reputed or not :P

This puzzle will provide a screenshot in somewhere on Google Earth, please try your best to identify where the location is. The reasons to find out the location should be part of your answer.

Will give a zoom-out image as the next hint if not be answered yet.

**Note:** It's not recommended to use Google Search by Image function(I'll try my best to avoid that when selecting the screenshot). **Try to use any feature on pixels or your geography knowledge to derive the location.**

---

**Question:**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that we are looking at the

> Pearl Harbor National Memorial [image] (image courtesy of https://www.nps.gov/valr/index.htm)

I guess the reason is that I've been there and I've seen many pictures of it? I don't know how to really answer that part.

Comment: You answered so fast...seems to easy i think :( . However the roof of the Memorial  is the same as the image? :P

Comment: Take for example the image on the monument's official website : https://www.nps.gov/valr/index.htm . And as for the difficulty level, I think in this case it's just a really recognizable monument (which is a testament to its designer!). I'm sure there are others that would be more difficult, although I'd try to avoid a test of "do you live near this part of the planet" and rather find places where you can reason/guess about it. It's a neat idea for a puzzle but it seems like a bit of a tightrope!

Comment: Yes, this puzzle seems like a trial. I'm thinking what picture should I pick, and I knew that I need to pick more common due to everyone in the PSE is so smart and great!