# Seven Places at Once - Another Google Earth Challenge?

Tags: visual, geography

<sub>This puzzle is based on [Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89071/where-is-it-the-google-earth-challenge-ep-1) series started by [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61486/conifers), :D</sub>

<sub>As usual, no reverse image are allowed.</sub>

---

> Hey, check these out! These seven places are so special because the devil from hell did an experiment to combine a chicken sandwich and popcorn by accident. Silly, now where are they?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there anything special about these seven places? Are they related?

Comment: @shoover The text above the pictures says yes, somehow.

Comment: Love it. Keep them coming!

Comment: I'm glad that my puzzle could be extended :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuing from Birjolaxew's discovery of

> Popcorn, Indiana, USA,

## 1 is

> **Accident**, Maryland, USA:
>
>  [image: Accident]

## 2 is

> **Chicken**, Alaska, USA:
>
>  [image: Chicken]

## 3 is

> **Devil** Town, Ohio, USA:
>
>  [image: Devil]

## 4 is

> **Experiment**, Georgia (state), USA:
>
>  [image: Experiment]

## 5 is

> **Hell**, Michigan, USA:
>
>  [image: Hell]

## 6 is

> **Popcorn**, Indiana, USA, as already discovered by [Birjolaxew](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89106/5373).
>
>  [image: Popcorn]

## 7 is

> **Sandwich**, Massachusetts, USA, as already discovered by [tjs352](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89103/seven-places-at-once-another-google-earth-challenge/89107#comment257239_89106).
>
>  [image: Sandwich]

So the connection is,

> as you said, the **devil** from **hell** doing an **experiment** to combine a **chicken** **sandwich** and **popcorn** by **accident**. I don't know if there's any significance to all the places chosen being in the USA - e.g. instead of choosing the more famous Sandwich in England which gave its name to the food called a sandwich - but the USA is certainly known for its odd place names which could be standard English words!

Comment: Just beat you to #3! (Maybe - at least it wasn't here before I posted)

Comment: @WeatherVane Just saw your answer - I guess we found it at the same time :-)

Comment: The whole thing makes me think of ROT13(ubj gur rssrpg bs zvpebjnirf ba sbbq jrer svefg qvfpbirerq ol nppvqrag, naq fbba qrzbafgengrq va choyvp ol pbbxvat fnaqjvpurf).

Comment: All of them are correct, well done! :D No particular "relation" actually here except the connection you wrote above. I thought it would be a bit impossible to solve without the hint so let the hint tells them right away!

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

> Judging by the map information written in the lower-right of each image, all these pictures are of the US. In two cases we get state information (#3 is in Ohio, #6 is in Indiana), which gives us a general area to search in.
>  
>  I only found the location of #6 and #7.
>
>  #6 is in Indiana, but has a lot of wooded areas. This made me focus on the south-western part of the state. The road in the top-left corner looks big enough that it's probably route 69 (judging by the angle), which led me to the area around [Popcorn, Indiana](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.98047,-86.672439,4498m/data=!3m1!1e3).
>
>  #7 is close to the ocean / a huge lake, and contains an airport. The shape of the peninsula is pretty unique, and at that scale it can be spotted easily from a zoomed out image. It matches [the area around Camp Edwards, Massachusetts](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.710079,-70.5392353,35604m/data=!3m1!1e3).

Comment: #7 reveals Sandwich, Massachusetts, indicated by "sandwich" in the hint. #6 points to "popcorn". My assumption is that the other locations will have associations to words in the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Partial: #3 is

> [***Devil*** Town, Wayne Township, OH, USA](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Devil+Town,+Wayne+Township,+OH+44691,+USA/@40.8453335,-81.9822333,2325m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x88374f5e710e351b:0xaac6095d387c02c7!8m2!3d40.8453344!4d-81.9734785)

Which I found with a bit of guesswork and hints from other answers.

Comment: +1's all around! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> #5 is [Hell, Michigan](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hell,+MI+48169/@42.4347191,-83.9937548,3430m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x882334578757ad71:0xd45079770956618a!8m2!3d42.43472!4d-83.985)

Comment: I think I found #5 before you, but you get my +1 for being the first to fully identify #7 (in a comment).