# Not Seven This Time - another Google Earth challenge

Tags: visual, no-computers, geography

Where is this?

[image: satellite view of mystery location]

Please don't use Google reverse image search, but solve the puzzle using inspiration and deduction.

Comment: Inspired by [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89071/5373) and [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89103/5373), although this puzzle is self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

The place you are looking for is

> Avebury, Wiltshire, UK

aka

> The Standing Stones of Avebury

[Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avebury)

Comment: Yep, well done. (Out of interest, how did you get it?) Now explain the second meaning of the title ;-)

Comment: see recent meta post ;) @Randal'Thor

Comment: and is there a second meaning of the title??

Comment: Well, well: I should have specified, as the previous posters did, that just using Google image search isn't allowed. I thought it was an unspoken assumption that puzzles should be solved by skill :-) And yes, there is a second meaning of the title, otherwise how would I expect you to find it?

Comment: @Randal'Thor sorry for spoiling your puzzle then :( should i delete my anwer?

Comment: Someone added the [tag:no-computers] tag after the meta discussion, so I added a line to say "no Google image search please".

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly, I've already spoiled myself by looking at [Omega Krypton's "solution"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89129/57742), but here's one plausible method to find it legitimately:

> The first thing I noticed was the prominent circular formation on the right. Since OP is probably not playing GeoGuessr, the formation has to have some sort of significance, otherwise it would be near impossible to find by conventional means. Thus, I started thinking about famous outdoor, circular structures, and the first one that came to mind was [Stonehenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge).  
>  
>  Unfortunately, the [area around Stonehenge](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stonehenge/@51.178882,-1.8284037,529m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4873e63b850af611:0x979170e2bcd3d2dd!8m2!3d51.178882!4d-1.826215) doesn't look anything like the provided image, so it looks like this is a dead end. However, upon further inspection of the Wikipedia page, it appears that the Stonehenge monument is actually one of [a group of locations that are collectively designated as a UNESCO World Heritage site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge,_Avebury_and_Associated_Sites); in particular, this site includes another outdoor circular monument called [Avebury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avebury) that could be promising. 
>  
>  Checking the satellite imagery, we find an [exact match](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Avebury/@51.4289196,-1.8570795,527m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48715c3293800313:0xd6131e27f8f5e5aa!8m2!3d51.4289196!4d-1.8548908) to the given image, so the location is **Avebury** in Wiltshire, England.

OP also [indicated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89126/not-seven-this-time-another-google-earth-challenge/89162#comment257312_89129) that there was a second meaning to the title. Well, even after finding the solution (sorta) legitimately, I still don't have any idea what else it could mean. Some thoughts:

> (A) Perhaps "ave" means "seven" and "bury" means "not" in some foreign language? I tried Google Translating "not seven" into a bunch of languages, but nothing useful came up. 
>  
>  (B) The title contains a lot of characters and character strings in common with "STONEHENGE" and "AVEBURY." Most notably, "[NOT S]even" contains part of "[STON]E" backwards, and"chall[ENGE]" contains a part of "H[ENGE]." But this could just be me reading too much into it.

Comment: Nice deduction! I was indeed expecting someone to think of the more famous one first and then try other possibilities. This one is particularly noteworthy because it's the largest of its kind in the world - if you know about these types of location in general, this one and the one everyone's heard of would likely be the first two to come to mind.

Comment: For the title meaning, geographical location may be helpful ...