# A big cat roams through the middle of this Google Earth hunt

Tags: riddle, visual, geography

<sub>This puzzle is based on [Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89071/where-is-it-the-google-earth-challenge-ep-1) series started by [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61486/conifers), :D</sub>

Note - this puzzle is mostly, if not all, about solving the riddle. I suppose the puzzle could exist without the image at all, and be perfectly solvalbe. If anything, the image should be used to confirm your solution to the riddle.

```
Don't get sidetracked - this is probably Denver's first.
Name the cartoon bear that loved honey.
Do you remember him, or at least where he likes to sleep?
In the woods! Of course.
```

I suppose a hint is in order.

> While the riddle has four lines, and they're all quite necessary, its solution only has three parts. Plus any hints I might have left lying around.

Another hint, then.

> To find the meaning hidden in the text, you will need to resort to an idiom that means exactly that.

I'll add to the second hint.

> The lines themselves are mostly red herrings. However, if you read between the lines...

[image: salmon digs]

Comment: no-computers tag? (Recent [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/google-earth-challenges-should-we-keep-them) discussion...)

Comment: @Stiv I put the image into google image search and nothing useful came out. This one is mostly meant to be solved using the riddle, to be honest. What's the tag for that?

Comment: @hdsdv As in the description of the tag [tag:no-computer], it is meant to indicate when it is *"A puzzle designed to be solved without using calculators, online decoders or computer programming"*.

Comment: @Zoma I understand, and I understand the specific application of it described in the meta post that Stiv linked. But in this case, I do not think that using Google's reverse image search will be of any use, so I'm not sure if the tag is necessary. There are many puzzles here that are not intended to be solved using a computer, but since a computer would be relatively useless in solving them, they do not have the no-computers tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still working on some of the clues, but I may have a lead on some.

**Don't get sidetracked - this is probably Denver's first**

> I believe that this is referring to John Denver.

Don't get side tracked

> I thought of train tracks and All Aboard! was John Denver's last album

This is probably Denver's first

> I think refers to his first studio album "Rhymes and Reasons" which has a song at the
>  beginning of the B side titled "Yellow Cat" maybe to do with the title of this post

More thoughts on this clue...

> Could the clue be referring to not getting sidetracked by not overthinking it? is it as simple as Denver's first letter or syllable?
>
>  Another idea is that it could be John Denver's first name which is Henry. (@hdsdv confirmed that **John** is correct) 
>
>
>  Using the logic that @Ahmed pointed out, we get Denver's first name by omitting the punctuation and just reading the clue straight through. Applying that same logic, it could be the cartoon bear that that loved **honeydew**. Possibly Yogi Bear because he ate human food.
>
>
>
>  Continuing this logic further would take "sleep" and "in" to give us **sleeping** 
>
>
>
>
>  Then the 3 words we have are **John, Honeydew, and Sleeping**. Pairing two of these (John and sleeping) with the title clue (cat) could be Garfield?

**Name the cartoon bear that loved honey.**

> I think this is Winnie the Pooh or maybe Baloo from The Jungle Book...
>
>  I found a [wiki page of fictional bears.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_bears) Maybe this can lead to something.
>
>
>
>  Reading between the lines this could also be meaning that the cartoon bear is named John. Little John from Robin Hood is the only one I know of. And he slept in Sherwood Forest. Then the last line could mean something like "of course" = sure and "woods" = forest... Just putting my thoughts out there, but translating that to a place on google maps didn't yield any significant results. Sherwood forest contains no lakes and lake Sherwood in West Virginia wasn't quite a match to the picture.

**Do you remember him, or at least where he likes to sleep?**

> Not much here other than if it's Winnie the Pooh, he lived in Pooh's Corner.

**In the woods! Of course.**

> Just a shot in the dark, but could be something to do with golf. "Course" like a golf course and "woods" as in Tiger Woods (also brings up the title again with the big cat thing).

**A big cat roams through the middle of this Google Earth hunt**

> In hint #1 "... any hints I might have left lying around." Could be like "... any hints I might have left **lion** around."

**Solved!**

> **John** Denver
>
>  Honeydew is a type of **Mellon**
>
>
>  When you sleep in the woods you **Camp**
>
>
>
>  The big cat roams that through the middle of this Google Earth hunt is a **Cougar**
>
>
>
>
>  [John Cougar Mellencamp's lake house](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.0818505,-86.4252092,853m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en-US)

Comment: There is some progress here :) And some red herrings... I will say that rot13(Vg'f abg Qraire'f svefg nyohz, ohg vg vf Qraire'f svefg fbzrguvat).

Comment: I think its actually rot13(Qraire'f svefg anzr, orpnhfr vs lbh ernq gur evqqyr vg fnlf "Qba'g trg fvqrgenpxrq - guvf vf cebonoyl Qraire'f svefg. Anzr gur pnegbba orne..." naq vs lbh ernq vg jvgubhg gur crevbq gur anzr pna tb jvgu obgu fragraprf.)

Comment: rot13(gung pbhyq or vg orpnhfr uvf svefg anzr vf npghnyyl urael)

Comment: @Ahmed is on the right track. Perhaps the same kind of logic can be applied elsewhere?

Comment: @GrumpyLlama59 for the purposes of this puzzle, and to avoid confusion since you've basically solved this part, I'll stipulate that rot13(Wbua Qraire'f svefg anzr vf "Wbua") :)

Comment: the two words you have in boldface (in spoilers) are both on the right track. why not apply the same logic in the other place? as implied by hint 3, don't get too hung up on a literal reading of the lines themselves

Comment: very close! rot13(whfg yvxr "Qraire'f svefg anzr" pyhrq "Wbua", "ubarlqrj" vfa'g va gur nafjre - vg pyhrf nabgure jbeq. Nyfb, whfg yvxr "Qraire'f svefg anzr" unf zber guna gjb jbeqf, gur guveq pyhr pna unir zber guna whfg gur gjb jbeqf "fyrrc va".)

Comment: Nice work! This was my first time trying a riddle, so I feel like I need to work on tightening up the structure of the cluing in some way. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: It was a little challenging with the wordplay, but very entertaining! Looking forward to your next puzzle!

Answer (score 2):

Just some small findings of mine:

Denver's first could also be

> His first wife, Anne Martell of St. Peter, Minnesota. Which could refer to Minnesota.
>  Or his first top ten album, Rocky Mountain High.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid it's none of those... and to point you in the right direction, I'll say that you won't need to guess what "first" it is - you can determine it from the riddle.

Answer (score 2):

I have most of an answer, but I'm stuck at a person rather than a place.  I'm sure there is a final step I'm still missing.

My partial answer is:

> John Cougar Mellencamp.  The method to solve is to look at the word clues that "overlap" each line.

So the real clues are:

> Don't get sidetracked - this is probably **Denver's first. Name** the cartoon bear that loved **honey.  Do** you remember him, or at least where he likes to **sleep? In** **the woods**! Of course.

This leads to:

> Denver's first name = John

Then:

> honey do = melon

Finally:

> sleep in the woods = camp

Putting them all together:

> John+melon+camp = John Mellencamp, who used to be known as John Cougar, then John Cougar Mellencamp.  This fits the title clue about a big cat roaming through the middle.  But I can't connect this to the pictured location ...

Comment: Solved by GrumpLlama59 while I was typing ...