# The Google Earth Challenge: "A dangerous flower"

Tags: visual, no-computers, geography

<sub>This puzzle is based on [Where is it? - The Google Earth Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89071/where-is-it-the-google-earth-challenge-ep-1) series started by [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61486/conifers)</sub>

This puzzle will provide a screenshot in somewhere on Google Earth, please try your best to identify where the location is. The reasons to find out the location should be part of your answer. The accepted answer will be the one which will explain the title of the question.

Will give a zoom-in image as the next hint if not be answered yet for a while.

Note: It's not recommended to use Google Search by Image function directly; try to use any feature on pixels or your geography knowledge to derive the location.

[image: Where is this place?]

Comment: Is the orientation correct? (north pointing up)

Comment: Huh. Pʀıncess Anaya posted an answer below and self-deleted it. I assumed she deleted the answer because it was wrong, so I didn't even check and went hunting for other things of the same type. Turns out, her answer is actually right! But now I don't want to post it and steal her credit. Voting to undelete her answer.

Comment: I supposed it would have been far too easy...

Comment: @Randal'Thor: yes sir, no rotation to the original orientation

Comment: @Randal'Thor I deleted the answer because I unable to figure our why dangerous flower?. I know the place is dangerous but why flower :P because of the ships in the images and dangerous i able to figure out he place.

Comment: I think the dangerous flower there is some poisonous flower which resemble the place...

Comment: @PʀıncessAnaya rot13(creuncf n sybjre vf fbzrguvat gung sybjf).

Comment: @PʀıncessAnaya builder... one who builds... flower...

Comment: @LeppyR64 yes, I got it... Genoa economy is totally depend on flower production...

Comment: Oh man using rot13 for public spoilers is GREAT :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This place is

> Isola del Giglio, Italy: On 13 January 2012, the Italian cruise ship Costa Concordia ran aground and overturned after striking an
>  underwater rock off Isola del Giglio, Tuscany, resulting in 32 deaths.
>  
>  
>
>  Reason can be to be known as dangerous flower that Giglio means "Lily" (flower) in Italian.

OP EDIT:
This is a close up image of the place:

> [image: costa concordia]

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place ... [it's not Genoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isola_del_Giglio). Check that location on Google Maps and you will see the same image :-)

Comment: You're mixing correct information with uncorrect ones... But, of course, you're close to the intended solution

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes, I previously edited Isola del Giglio. then I changed to genoa... and was searching on the google map :P

Comment: @Hunter Is it correct now?

Comment: @PʀıncessAnaya: yes, except the part about Genoa that is not relevant. As stated, the photo isn't actual anymore, (rot13) univat gur fuvc orvat zbirq gb gur cbeg bs Trahn va 2014. Gur fuvc erznvarq ba gur pbnfg bs Tvtyvb'f Vfynaq sbe 2 lrnef naq unys.

Comment: How does the 'dangerous' part of the question title match with this answer?

Comment: @jarnbjo Isola del Giglio was a dangerous flower for Costa Concordia. It is known for one of the biggest disaster that is why it is dangerous.

Comment: @PʀıncessAnaya Sorry, but that was too far fetched for me. Ships have probably sunk around all islands in the Mediterranean. I don't see why your answer should me any more dangerous than other islands.

Comment: @jarnbjo: honestly I don't think there is nothing far fetched in the question: "giglio" in italian means "lily", a flower. This "flower" resulted extremely dangerous for the Costa Concordia boat which sunk after approaching too near to it. PS: anyway "dangerous flower" isn't a "nickname" for Giglio's Island, as supposed by the answerer

Answer (score 0):

I think this location is in:

> Italy - Liguria - Genoa [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_City_of_Genoa#/media/File:Aerial_view_-_Harbour_of_Genoa,*Italy*-_DSC01156.JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_City_of_Genoa#/media/File:Aerial_view_-_Harbour_of_Genoa,_Italy_-_DSC01156.JPG)

Was here on holiday a few years back, not sure the flower part yet

Comment: Not the right place. (PS: Actually Genoa is in Liguria, not in Tuscany)

Comment: @Hunter and here is me thinking I've only ever visited the Tuscany region. Thanks for the correction.